# I need to solve this equation numerically but don't have access to any software...

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to solve this equation numerically, but I don't have access to any software:

$$2^{1-t} \log \tfrac12 = a(t) \log a(t)$$

where $a(t):= 2^{-t} + \tfrac12$.

The logs are natural logarithms.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can access the internet, apparently. https://www.google.com/search?q=calculator&btnG=Go

Comment: If I was absolutely sure I knew what you were trying to solve (solve for $t$, $a(t)$ ...?, any particular method?, is this typeset accurately?...)  I could probably point you to some software, maybe even online.

Comment: I am trying to solve for t. I only used a(t) to make the expression clearer. There was a typo which I have corrected now.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha [came up with](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%281-t%29+*+log%28.5%29+%3D+%282%5E%28-t%29+%2B+.5%29*log%282%5E%28-t%29+%2B+.5%29) $t \approx 2.42397516638965$ but I haven't checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can use the web, you do have access to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%281-t%29%20*%20log%281/2%29%20=%20%282%5E%28-t%29%20%2b%201/2%29%20*%20log%282%5E%28-t%29%20%2b%201/2%29), which says the answer is approximately $t \approx 2.42397516638965$.

Ps. If you'd like to inspect the solution visually, you can also tell Wolfram Alpha to [plot each side of your equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%202%5E%281-t%29%20*%20log%281/2%29,%20%282%5E%28-t%29%20%2b%201/2%29%20*%20log%282%5E%28-t%29%20%2b%201/2%29%20from%202%20to%203), giving you a pretty picture where you can see where the lines cross:

[image: plot of 2^(1-t) * log(1/2) and (2^(-t) + 1/2) * log(2^(-t) + 1/2) from 2 to 3]

This can sometimes be useful e.g. for checking that there really are no other solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did spent quite a while trying to find software that would accept my equation online but didn't come across this one!